# Хранение изображений и тег img

Tags: html, изображения, img

Добрый день.

Существует вид хранения изображений в теге img (строчки вида "base64/JPEG..."). 
Как мне лучше хранить изображения-просто в отдельной таблице базе данных,или в поле с текстом статьи например записывать весь тег img с этой строчкой?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего хранить изображения в файловой системе, а в поле с текстом схранять только URL-картинок. 
Не насилуйте БД. Зачем каждый раз забирать из БД в память BLOB картинки, если можно взять только ее URL?

Comment: почему блоб???  
там теги вида: < img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAAA8AAD/4QRaaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjMtYzAxMSA2Ni4xND... и т.д.

Comment: У картинок размер в пределах иконки (16-64px) или возможны несколько сотен килобайт на фотку? Если картинки будут побольше, то этого "текста" будет в разы больше.

Чем вам не нравится src типа http://site.com/path/to/image.jpg? В чем причина такого рвения использовать именно data:image?

Answer (score 1):

base64 нужен для маленьких изображений, спрайтов. Для больших его лучше не использовать.

Если используете base64 - то можно хранить и в базе. Лучше в отдельной таблице или в отдельной ячейке хотя бы. Мешать текст с тегами - плохая практика.

Если base64 не используете и не нужно шифрование - в базе изображения не храните. Храните на сервере. А в базу пишите только ссылку.

Comment: Почему бы и не хранить текст с тегами?

Comment: Почему хранить текст с тегами плахоя практика?
Пока сервис находится в тестировании и вносятся правки в методы обработки - не спорю, но в "боевой" версии лучше каждый раз при выводе обрабатывать строку или же просто обработать ее при сохранении, а потом просто выводить?

Comment: Зачем ее обрабатывать, я понять не могу

Comment: Если понадобится заменить картинку в тексте или обновить - придется перелопачивать текст, делать разбивку на подстроки, менять и т.д.
Куда проще будет просто обновить отдельную ячейку в таблице.

P.S. И вообще не вижу смысла хранить теги в базе данных. Теги надо вынести в шаблон страницы. А из базы доставать только текст, ссылки и т.п.

Comment: А текст разве на в WYSIWIG редактируется? О_о
Или мы говорим о разных применениях текста?

Comment: При чем тут где он редактируется? Речь о том где он хранится. Если вы его храните в базе данных, то редактируйте хоть в WYSIWIG, хоть в Word, но теги и картинки в него совать не надо. Храните все по отдельности. Теги - в шаблоне страницы. Картинки - на сервере. Текст - в базе данных. Все.

Comment: Бывают сервисы с сотнями тысяч хитов в сутки, с таким способом хранения НИ ОДИН серв не справится таская картинки из БД и обратно, не говоря уже о сервере БД. Или же держать для каждого менее более серьезного проекта целый кластер? дороговато. 

База данных предназначена для данных. Бинарники должны хранится в файловой системе, оперативная память не резиновая. Все